# Building gremlin-plugin for neo4j

Tags: maven, neo4j, gremlin

I'm trying to install the gremlin-plugin so I can use neo4django in python. I tried to follow the steps laid out at https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin but I haven't had any success.

I have

1. downloaded gremlin-plugin-master.zip
2. `unzip gremlin-plugin-master.zip`
3. `cd gremlin-plugin-master/`
4. `mvn clean package`

At which point, I receive a message which contains the following snippit

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project neo4j-gremlin-plugin: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/mint/Downloads/gremlin-plugin-master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/plugin/gremlin/GremlinPlugin.java:[79,23] method autoStartTransaction in class com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.Neo4j2Graph cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR] required: boolean
[ERROR] found: no arguments
[ERROR] reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
....
```

Does anybody know what this means? I couldn't find anything that seemed to match this kind of error in this context and I have no idea where to start debugging this.

```
$ mvn -v
    Apache Maven 3.0.4
    Maven home: /usr/share/maven
    Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /usr/lib/jdk1.7.0_51/jre
    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-12-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

---

**EDIT:**

After cloning the repo, I was able to compile.

Comment: Did you freshly clone / update it? I fixed that issues today.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Yep, that fixed it. I was using the .zip file, then I pulled the SVN. They all seem to be different. But it works with the current git clone. Thanks.

Comment: Please mark the question as solved then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fresh clone of the repo solved the issue.